# How does Gradient.Evaluate work internally?

Tags: unity-game-engine, gradient, evaluation

I have been trying to make a structure similar to Unity's built-in `Gradient`.

What I'm stuck at getting my head around is the `Gradient.Evaluate` function, how does it work internally?

Any code snippets will be really helpful!

Note: I'm not using Unity that's why I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A color consists of 4 components: RGBA. Red - Green - Blue - Alpha

These components are stored as integers between 0-255.

White is: (1,1,1,1)

Black is: (0,0,0,1)

If the A value is not 1, then the color is transparent.

When you calculate a Gradient, you're probably asking about blend mode. In blend mode you're interpolating a value between 2 keys. Let's say for an example you have the following 2 colors:

```
colorA = (0,0,1,1) //This is blue
colorB = (1,0,0,1) //This is red
```

Let's simplify the gradient calculation with some pseudo-code:

```
gradient.ColorKey[0].color = colorA;
gradient.ColorKey[0].time = 0f;
gradient.ColorKey[1].color = colorB;
gradient.ColorKey[1].time = 2f;

gradient.Evaluate(0f); 
// (0,0,1,1)
gradient.Evaluate(0.6f); // 0.6 seconds in, or 70% key0 and 30% key1
// 0.7 * (0,0,1,1) + 0.3 * (1,0,0,1) = 
//(0.3, 0, 0.7, 1)
gradient.Evaluate(1.8f); // 1.8 seconds in, or 10% key0 and 90% key1
// 0.1 * (0,0,1,1) + 0.9 * (1,0,0,1) = 
//(0.9, 0, 0.1, 1)
gradient.Evaluate(2f); 
// (1,0,0,1)
```

If your gradient had more than 2 keys, the gradient calculation only uses the 2 keys neighboring the evaluation time. For example:

```
A (0,0,1,1) at 0s
B (1,0,0,1) at 1s
C (0,1,0,1) at 2s

gradient.Evaluate(0.7f); //results in 30% of A + 70% of B (0.7, 0, 0.3, 1)
gradient.Evaluate(1.5f); //results in 50% of B + 50% of C (0.5, 0.5, 0, 1)
```